# Expected expression in WRITE statement at (1)

Tags: fortran

So it's a simple helloworld program
    !sample program
    program main
    implicit none
    integer i
    real x

```
write(6,*) ’Hello World!’
x=0
do i=1,10
x=x+i
if(mod(i,2).eq.0) then
write(6,*) i,x
else
if(x.lt.3) write(6,*) x,i
end if
end do

end
```

and the error goes

```
 write(6,*) ’Hello World!’
           1
Error: Expected expression in WRITE statement at (1)
```

Comment: can we guess you are using some awful microsoft abomination for a text editor?

Comment: First, please use named constants from `ISO_Fortran_env` instead of hard-coding file identification units. Second, why not use modern operators to improve readability, e.g., `if (x < 3)` instead of `if (x .lt. 3)`. I also suspect that you're writing fixed-form code instead of free-form which in turn leads to a host of easily avoidable traps.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're using curly quotes around `Hello world`. Replace them with straight quotes and it'll work

So replace

```
write(6,*) ’Hello World!’
```

with

```
write(6,*) 'Hello World!'
```